# Get rid of extra variable in boolean algebra

Tags: boolean, algebra

I have a simple boolean expression: `(a & !b) | (!a & !c)`. As you can see `a` is in both AND statements. How can I rewrite this expression with only one "a" (is it even possible)?

Comment: You can use [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28a+and+not+b%29+or+%28not+a+and+not+c%29) for this type of analysis.

Comment: a little bit simpler expression would be: (a & !b) | !(a || c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is the simplest according to your specification this will get. You can not get rid of the second a.

There are [online tools](http://www.wolframalpha.com/i) to help you with boolean algebra, btw.

Comment: I have but I couldn't do it in less than 6 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Is `!((a&(c^b))^c)` what you are looking for?